# How to trigger communication with backend from Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I want to click on a push notification on my Apple Watch trigger communication with backend and show the results in a table on my Apple Watch.

I know how to show the result in a table on my Apple Watch. I also know the `openParentApplication:reply:` method.

But if I want to trigger my backend communication in `application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:` I get a error that `reply()` is never called. It seems that iOS kill this method if it takes to much time.

If I test `application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:` with a hard coded dictionary with only one entry, all works fine.

That is the recommended way to do this?

In my opinion I should do something in NotificationController.swift in `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method and app group but how can I trigger the backend communication on my iPhone?

UPDATE:

Part of my code in AppDelefate.swift:

```
    func application(application: UIApplication!, handleWatchKitExtensionRequest userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, reply: (([NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void)!) {
        var workaround: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier?
        workaround = UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler({
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(workaround!)
        })

        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(workaround!)
        })

        var realBackgroundTaks: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier?
        realBackgroundTaks = UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler({                
            reply(nil)
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(realBackgroundTaks!)
        })

        let testDict = ["Hello" : "World"]
        reply(testDict)

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(realBackgroundTaks!)
    }
```

This code works fine.
But if I change testDict to the backend communication code this method will killed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I found the solution for my problem. You can not pass custom objects in the reply dictionary, you have to use primitive types.

The splution is described on the following page from Kristina Thai.

http://realm.io/news/watchkit-mistakes/

Comment: Thank you! No doubt Apple docs says only primitives can be passed but I missed it and couldn't figure out why the iOS companion app wouldn't launch. The simulator is also a bit stubborn requiring the iOS app to be tapped to launch a few times.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to start a background task on the iPhone to ensure your app isn't killed in the background before your API request can complete. I've shared some resources in a similar answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29848521/3704092

Comment: Is this really the preferred way to do this from Apple?

Comment: The first link is the "official" word from Apple. The second is a solution that came out of discussions with an Apple engineer in labs.

Comment: Thank you very much for this hint. I've read for article on fiveminutewatchkit.com but it does not work for me.

I translate your code to Swift. Maybe I make a mistake. I'll insert my code in my question above. I hope you can help me.

Comment: Can you say how much time in seconds I have with this background task until the method will killed from iOS?

Comment: It's determined by the OS, taking into account a number of factors. I'm not sure if it's documented anywhere, but I couldn't tell you with any certainty.

Comment: Okay, e.g. I need 20 sec for my backend communication because of a slow wifi connection. Would this workaround with background tasks work in my case?

Comment: You should do your work in a background task either way, but it should be fine. I would also look at ways to reduce the amount of time that request takes, if possible.

Comment: But for me it seems to be the right place where I implement my testDict. Isn't it? If I put there my code for backend communication I get this error (The UIApplicationDelegate in the iPhone App never called reply() in -[UIApplicationDelegate application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:]) in my WatchKit App. I can not reduce the amount of time that request takes.

Comment: Is this maybe only a problem of the simulator?