# WatchKit : handleWatchKitExtensionRequest stops working after x amount of time

Tags: ios, watchkit

I am building a watch extension that uses handleWatchKitExtensionRequest to get the iPhone app to refresh its data which populates Shared Prefs (App Group).

So each time I load the app it calls handleWatchKitExtensionRequest on the iPhone app and everything works fine for like 15 minutes, then it just stops responding?

The watch app is still working, its just the iPhone app goes to sleep?  Whats the point of handleWatchKitExtensionRequest if not to ask the iPhone to do something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you doing your work in a background task? Check out this answer for a bit of an explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29848521/3704092

Comment: I'm already using a background task but still experiencing the same problematic behavior. Without the background task, it never works when in background, with it, it works only for some time and stops working.